# How to rotate an mp4 video in Android

Tags: android, android-video-player

I'm struggling with the infamous front camera mirrored playback so I'd like to rotate the output video so the player would play it in the right way.

Do you know which parameter I should set to make the mp4 video upside down? Is there any encoder class that could process the video?

I already set these values:

```
Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
Camera.getCameraInfo(1, info);
int result = (info.orientation) % 360;
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation((360 - result) % 360);
```

and

```
mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
```